# clear checked radio button value from form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code which represents a few radio buttons.

```
<label>Tipologia Pdv: </label>
<input type="radio" name="tipologia_pdv" id="tipologia_pdv" value="Iper" style="width:40px;" /><span > Iper</span>
<input type="radio" name="tipologia_pdv" id="tipologia_pdv"
value="Super" style="width:40px;" /><span > Super</span>
```

Then, i have this code which clears the value, but it doesnt work with radio buttons:

```
  $("#tipologia_pdv").val('');
```

Now, how would i get the to clear the checked value here? 
I assign the checked value with this and it works:

```
var js_tipologia_pdv = $('input:radio[name=tipologia_pdv]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#tipologia_pdv').attr('checked', false);
```

Prop works also

```
$('#tipologia_pdv').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: Use `prop` over `attr` in later versions of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks you, i'll accpet your answer in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tipologia_pdv").prop("checked", false);
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: The official documentation for jquery is at [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/) and is more up-to-date than jqapi.com.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the two radio buttons have the same id. ID should be unique..

The checked property is different than the val property .. To uncheck it you have to do this

```
var js_tipologia_pdv = $('input:radio[name=tipologia_pdv]:checked');

 js_tipologia_pdv.prop('checked', false);
```

check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/AWuWe/2/)